# Cannot select java vm when installing eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install Eclipse 2019-09 version, but it wanted me to Select a Java 17 64 Bit VM while I want to use Java 10 in system.

[image: screenshot]

I tried to click jdk 10-0-2 at the system location but it did not recognized, so i went to Eclipse download page to see if 2019-09 if it is compatible with java10 and it says it is ok if i use higher version than java8. Next I opened cmd and input `-javac version` to if it is successfully installed and it worked so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: 1)  You say that you are trying to install Eclipse 2019-09, but the installer seems to have chosen jee-2022-09 as the default installation directory.  That implies that you have not downloaded the 2019-09 installer!  2) Don't use Java 10.  Seriously.  It is end-of-life.  If you *have to* use an old version of Java, use Java 8 or Java 11 ... and make sure you have the latest patch release available.

Comment: Choose the recommended external JRE 17.0.7 to be installed as part of Eclipse to run Eclipse. Independent from that, configure the Java VMs you want to use in your project in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse 4.25 (2022-09) requires a JVM 17 or greater](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.25_.282022-09.29) to execute Eclipse. After Eclipse is installed and launched you can select other versions of the JVM to build and execute your projects.